# Rotation and turning of marker on right end of line

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, markers

Having a line in `Matplotlib` with assigning marker-end. How can I rotate and turn marker symbol at one end.

Current line with marker.

[image]

Wanted line with marker-end

[image]

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal')
linea = Line2D((0.1, 0.9), (0.5, 0.5), linewidth=10, color="fuchsia", 
               alpha=0.6,  marker='$∖$', markersize=20)
ax.add_line(linea)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always could plot line and marker separately:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal')

line = ((0.1, 0.5, 0.9), (0.5, 0.7, 0.5))
linea = Line2D(*line, linewidth=10, color="fuchsia", alpha=0.6)
ax.add_line(linea)
ax.plot(line[0][:-1], line[1][:-1], ls="", color="fuchsia", alpha=0.6, 
        marker='$∖$', markersize=30)
ax.plot(line[0][-1], line[1][-1], ls="", color="fuchsia", alpha=0.6, 
        marker='$/$', markersize=30)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. It works perfectly, Exactly what I want! :)

Comment: Unfortunately this solution shows the linestyle and markerstyle in separate entries in the legend (if enabled).

Comment: The ```markevery=[0, -1]``` option does the job. More info on this keyword can be found in https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/gallery/